# Can I run an ASP.NET 3.5 application on a server with ASP.NET 4.0 installed without any problems?

Tags: asp.net

Can I run an ASP.NET 3.5 application on a server with ASP.NET 4.0 installed without any problems? I am hosting a large number of website on a Godaddy server with ASP.Net 2.0/3.0/3.5 installed. However, my newest application needs 4.0 to run. If I upgrade the server to 4.0, will all my other sites break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 4.0 application needs it's own 4.0 application pool. No, your other sites won't break. You aren't really "upgrading" the server, you are just installing the 4.0 framework.

Comment: Make sure to test this first on a local machine.

Comment: Just read somewhere on the Godaddy website that applications that run under version 1.1 may not run under newer runtime versions. Applications that run under runtime versions 2.0 and above should run under newer runtime versions. All my sites are at least 2.0. I just made the change over to ASP.Net 4.0/4.5 and everything appears to be okay. Thanks Brad!